# iOS change keyboard button

Tags: ios, button, uikeyboard, alphabet

[image]

Is that possible to change the **+ * #** button to **Next** button? And remove the alphabets from number *(2 to 9)*?

**NOTE: this is `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad`**

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad` buttons, only you will customize view for `UIKeybord` in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the built-in keyboards, but you can make a custom keyboard that has the modifications you want.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html